# Implementing jQuery Autocomplete in many inputs in a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I have an autocomplete which takes results from google suggestions. On a page I have multiple input fields which I'd like to include that function so that all inputs will be taking results from google suggestion and using the jquery autocomplete widget.

Here is a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8q25P/

Note on the first input it parse's google queries. On the second which has different ID its where I want to implement the feature aswell.

Thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the changes..

http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/ag9gv/

---

First you need to apply the autocomplete to both elements and also bind the `retrieve` to both.

```
$('#q, #w').keyup(retrieve);
```

and

```
$('#q, #w').autocomplete({
        source: []
    });
```

You also need to change your ajax call and the retrieve method a bit, to make the related element auto-discoverable.. (*create a variable and pass it to the success method*)

```
function retrieve() {
    var _this = this;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?qu=' + encodeURIComponent($(this).val()),
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(data){parse(data,_this);}
    });
}

var parse = function(data,element) {
    var results = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data[1].length; i++) {
         results.push(data[1][i][0]);
    }
    $(element).autocomplete({
        source: results
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to each input and bind the autocomplete to an input with a class of that class

```
$(input.class).autocomplete()
```